# pybind11 how to add C++ dependencies using setup.py

Tags: python, c++, c++11, pybind11

(I am new to Python and Python binding) 
I have a C++ package which uses FCL library, and its data types. The code is working in C++, but when I try to use Pybind11 to access it in Python, it compiles without error, but when I import it in Python I get the error:

> undefined symbol: _ZTVN3fcl3BoxE

Heres my setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
def get_pybind_include():
    import pybind11
    return pybind11.get_include()
import sys
extra_compile_args = ['--std=c++11','-lfcl','-libccd']
ext_modules = [Extension('Coll', ['src/Coll.cpp'],
                         library_dirs=['lib'],
                         include_dirs=['include',
                                       get_pybind_include()],

                         language='c++',
                         extra_compile_args=extra_compile_args), ]

setup(name='Coll',
      version='0.1',
      description='Python bindings for the Coll v1',
      setup_requires=['fcl'],
      ext_modules=ext_modules,
)
```

Seems to be problem with linking FCL library, how can I make sure its linked?

EDIT: I am on virtual environment, not sure if this has effect.

Comment: With your C++ code how do you link with the FCL library ? If FCL is compiled as a dynamic library maybe check your PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: its a dynamic library.  heres the echo of PATH
/usr/local/lib:/home/..(virtualEnv directory):/home/XX/bin:/home/XX/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

and echo of LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/local/lib
(one thing I forgot to mention is that I am working in a Virtual environment)

Comment: When you launcher your c++ program is the .so next to exécutable or is it un /usr/local/lib ?

Comment: Don't confuse compilation and linking. extra_compile_args are for compilation, extra_link_args are for linking.

Comment: @P.E.Normand An undefined symbol doesn't mean a library was not found, it means it was not searched in the first place.

Comment: @n.m. surely has the answer then extra_linking_args = ['--std=c++11','-lfcl','-libccd']. Question about where is the libfcl.so is still relevant.

Comment: @P.E.Normand since OP can run standalone programs linked against libfcl.so, this question already has a satisfactory answer.

Comment: But does OP know ?

Comment: the standalone c++ program works, I am compiling it with "g++  -o col Coll.cpp -lfcl  -std=c++11" as I link the fcl library as you mentioned. The problem is with python binding, how to link the fcl library for pybind11 setup.py?